# Verify IP string is greater or less than another IP string in python

Tags: python, string, ip

In a sample code I am taking start IP and end IP as input . Out of which I will create a list of IP pool. I want to add a validation that start IP should be always lesser than end IP.

```
start_ip = '100.71.9.98'
end_ip = '100.71.9.100'

start_ip < end_ip 

False
```

How can I validate that start_ip should be lesser than end_ip ?

Comment: one liner: print [int(n) for n in start_ip.split('.')] < [int(n) for n in end_ip.split('.')]

Comment: good comprehension but I don't know the complexity for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the strings to a list of ints.

```
>>> start_ip = '100.71.9.98'
>>> end_ip = '100.71.9.100'
>>> map(int, start_ip.split('.'))  # list(map(int, ...))  in Python 3.x
[100, 71, 9, 98]
>>> map(int, end_ip.split('.'))
[100, 71, 9, 100]
```

Then, it's possible to compare them as you want:

```
>>> '100.71.9.98' < '100.71.9.100'
False
>>> [100, 71, 9, 98] < [100, 71, 9, 100]
True
>>> map(int, start_ip.split('.')) < map(int, end_ip.split('.'))
True
```

Comment: Perfect ! I had a different impression of string comparison.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Python 3.x then you can use the [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) stdlib package which has objects designed for ip addresses. These objects support comparison in this way.

```
import ipaddress

start = ipaddress.IPv4Address('100.71.9.98')
end = ipaddress.IPv4Address('100.71.9.100')

print(start < end)
# True
```

[py2-ipaddress](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2-ipaddress/) can be used (with some reduced functionality) if you are using Python 2.7.

Comment: Actually I was using netaddr library which takes care of this things. But I am writing my own method to implement that. Basically want to get rid of extra library. :) any how good to know about py2-address

Answer (score 0):

Standard ipaddress libray (IPv4/IPv6 manipulation library) works like charm:

```
import ipaddress 

if ipaddress.ip_address('192.0.2.1') < ipaddress.ip_address('192.0.2.2'):
    ...
```